# Android Clang 5.0 omp_in_parallel returns 0

Tags: android, c++, multithreading, openmp

I am trying to run below OpenMP code on android but it doesn't seem to work.Can someone please explain if I am missing something?

I am using -fopenmp for compilation and linking.

```
 CFLAGS += -fopenmp
 LDFLAGS += -fopenmp
```

Compiler - Clang 5.0

Linker - LLVM

Device - Nexus 7

Os - Android 6.0.1

```
    omp_set_num_threads(4); //initialise thread count for 4 core cpu   
    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(4)
    for( int i = 1; i< 10; i++ )
    {
       std::string out = std::to_string( omp_in_parallel() );
       androidLog( out.c_str() );
    }
```

Comment: Not the answer to your problem, but check whether the `androidLog` function is thread-safe. If not, you have to synchronize its calls, e.g., by using `#pragma omp critical`.

Comment: Did you get this to work?

Comment: @rpattabi no i still don't know why it didn't work

Comment: I tried it now, it works fine with recent NDK r17. I use CMake and `-fopenmp` is not needed for linker. Instead linked with `omp` library.

Comment: @rpattabi may be i was using old arm abi lib with update it works for me too..